# Bootstrap4 nav-tab changes page instead of chaging tab content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to add a bootstrap nav-tab element to a page on my angular site. I just copied some example code from here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior

When I tried it on that page it works fine, but when I click the tabs on my page it opens the href of the tab (changes the url) instead of changing the tab content.

I thought it might be a problem with how I imported bootstrap or jQuery or something, so I changed the CDN link from the angular example code to what bootstrap has on their website. I haven't tried importing the standalone tab javascript plugin, but I couldn't find a CDN link for that.

This is how I'm importing everything.

```
<!-- Vendor: Javascripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Vendor: Angular, followed by our custom Javascripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the nav-tab code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked with the CDN paths given on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/)...

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Vendor: Angular, followed by our custom Javascripts -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that works for me too, but when I put it in my angular page the same thing happens, the url changes to the href/id of the tab like so: http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/menu1 Could it be because I'm using angular partials?

Comment: If you can share the code which replicates this behavior, it'll be easier to help